# My xsl-fo stylesheet don't add my page number prefix as expected

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I'm trying to change the way the index page works by adding to it a number present in the xml. so in theory this is supposed to be made out of the box, but for some reason the output doesn't have my page-number prefix.

for example, if the node somethingElse has the value, 57 and is on the page 13 I want to have 57.13 displayed on the index but only 13 gets displayed.

I tried to change value-of/inline to a block conataining only a word test, but even that doesn't seem to work. So I can only assume that I'm not using index-page-number-prefix correctly...

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline font-weight="normal">
    <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
        <fo:index-page-citation-list>
            <fo:index-key-reference ref-index-key="{.};{../title};;" font-weight="bold">
                <fo:index-page-number-prefix>
                    <fo:inline>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::something/SomethigElse"/>.
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:index-page-number-prefix>
            </fo:index-key-reference>
        </fo:index-page-citation-list>
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Hopefully `SomethigElse` in your sample is just a typo and you are using the correct XPath in your real XSLT.  Are you getting the `.` before the `13`? (Actually, you'll probably see `. ` because the whole text node with the `.` in it will be copied into your result tree: use `xsl:text` around just the `.` or put the `</fo:inline>` immediately after the `.`.)  You don't need the `fo:inline` at all. Which formatter are you using?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @TonyGraham Hi, To answer your question : I am not seeing the "." which is the weirdest part of my question. Also, even when I removed fo:inline, it didn't worked. As for my formatter I am using RenderX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fo:index-page-number-prefix` is ignored by RenderX.  See http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#XSL11_Support or, more specifically, http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#XSL11_Indexes.

Comment: Well.... I'll accept your answer since it answers why it was not working haha :)   By any chance do you have an idea on how to have the same functionnaly with RenderX ?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I use AH Formatter (as you would expect), which does support the FO.  @kevin-brown may have a workaround.